# Make a Cluster without using MongoDB Atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, nodes, cluster-computing

I am looking for how to make a cluster without using MongoDB Atlas and I can't find anything, if you could give me a page, video or reference I would appreciate it.

Everything I find about MongoDB cluster uses Atlas. I need to do development on a local host and Atlas uses the cloud.

I'm trying to make a cluster with nodes in a MongoDB database and JAVA language but I can't find anything to solve this problem, I know the theory but I need some practical example or documentation. All the tutorials or documents that I found in a week are for MongoDB Atlas but I can't use the cloud.

TKS!

Comment: Follow [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) or much better [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Mongo Cluster on local machines with docker/linux. You can find a guide here: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/clusters/mongodb-cluster-setup

> Creating a MongoDB Cluster in Different Environments
>
> If a cloud-based instance of MongoDB is not an option for you, or if you need to run a cluster on your infrastructure, you can install MongoDB on supported operating systems. In addition to MongoDB itself, installing Ops Manager or Cloud Manager is recommended to manage your clusters.
> Create a MongoDB Cluster in Linux (Ubuntu, CoreOS)
>
> To create a MongoDB cluster in Linux, you will need three instances of MongoDB running. These instances need to be able to communicate with each other on a local network.
>
> You can find the detailed instructions to set up your cluster in Linux in the documentation.
> Create a MongoDB Cluster with Docker
>
> If you want to install a local instance of MongoDB in your environment or set up an ephemeral development environment that you can share with your teammates, you might want to use Docker. You can do so by starting three local instances of MongoDB in Docker, then following the instructions in the documentation.